# Python find succesive numbers in array/list

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array like this `arr = [1,2,3,10,11,15]` from which I want to have the numbers left and right of each block of successive numbers, i.e. [0,4,9,12,14,16].

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, but it is not worth mentioning because it does not work at all.

Comment: From the desired result it seems that the numbers do not have to be successive. `15` is handled the same way. You can definitely write a very verbose and explicit `for` loop. It will not be elegant but you can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
arr = [1,2,3,10,11,15]
new_list = []
for m, n in groupby(enumerate(arr), lambda (i, x): i-x):
    t = map(itemgetter(1), n) 
    new_list.append(t[0]-1)
    new_list.append(t[-1]+1)

new_list
Out[]: [0, 4, 9, 12, 14, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you'd want to go over the array in a loop which checks if the number at index[i] is greater than that at index[i+1] and stores it in an array/prints it to console/ect. if that check is true (or false, depending on how you want to do that.)

Comment: is that supposed to be an answer?

Comment: According to the "question" ...  yes

Answer (score 0):

an unpretty way of doing this:

```
def getMissing( lst ):
    a = sorted(lst) # in case its not already sorted
    a.append( a[-1] + 10000) #insert one dummy bigger to ease iteration
    missing = []

    for i in xrange(len(a)-1):
        if a[i] - a[i-1] != 1:
            missing.append( a[i] -1)
        if a[i+1] - a[i] != 1:
            missing.append( a[i] +1)
    return missing    

print getMissing([1,2,3,10,11,15])
```